# Firebase is receiving requests but view won't show data

Tags: swift, swiftui

I have an app that works fine reading a JSON file but when I try to change the code to read the data from Firebase - after following a simpler tutorial - it does not show the data.

As a slight aside. I am only able to figure out how to import my JSON to the Realtime database and not Firestore. If it's not possible to import JSON to Firestore the I will need to rethink the approach as I aren't going to add all 7000 products by hand.

ProductDetail creates the style for a single product

```
struct ProductDetail: View {
    @State private var username: String = ""
    @State var product: Product_
    
    var body: some View {
        
        VStack{
            Text(product.product_name)
                .fontWeight(.bold)
                .font(.title)
                .padding()
            HStack{
            Text("EAN Code:")
                Text(product.code).padding()
            }
        VStack(alignment: .leading){
            HStack{
                Text("Brand:")
                    .fontWeight(.bold)
                Text(product.brands)
                .padding()
            }
                Text("Packaging:")
                    .fontWeight(.bold)
                VStack{
                    VStack(alignment: .leading){
                        
                HStack{
                    // If packaging1 has some value other than Unknown then show packaging1
                    if product.packaging1 != "Unknown" {
                        Text(product.packaging1)
                        .padding()
                    Text("Outcome")
                    }
                    
                    // Otherwise include a button
                    else{
                        Button("Add Packaging"){}
                        .cornerRadius(8)
                    }
                }
                        
                HStack{
                    if product.packaging1 != "Unknown" || product.packaging2 != "Unknown" {
                        Text(product.packaging2)
                        .padding()
                    Text("Outcome")
                    }
                    else if product.packaging1 != "Unknown" || product.packaging2 == "Unknown"{
                        Button("Add Packaging"){}
                        .cornerRadius(8)
                    }
                    
                }
                        
                HStack{
                    if product.packaging1 != "Unknown" || product.packaging2 != "Unknown" || product.packaging3 != "Unknown"{
                        Text(product.packaging3)
                        .padding()
                    Text("Outcome")
                    }
                    else {
                        Button("Add Packaging"){}
                        .cornerRadius(8)
                    }
                }
                        
               }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

ProductList provides a navigation view list of all the products.

```
struct ProductList: View {
    @State private var searchText: String = ""
    
    @ObservedObject private var viewModel = ProductsModel()
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView{
            VStack{
                //SearchBar(text: $searchText)
                List(products, id: \.product_name) { product in
                NavigationLink(destination: ProductDetail(product: product))
                {ItemRow(product: product).navigationTitle("Products")
                }

            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is the structure that each product in the JSON (and soon to be Firebase) has.

```
struct Product_: Hashable, Codable{
    var code: String
    var brands: String
    var product_name: String
    var packaging1: String
    var packaging2: String
    var packaging3: String
}
```

This is basically the tutorial code but replaced with Products rather than books.

```
import Foundation
import FirebaseFirestore

class ProductsModel: ObservableObject{
    
    @Published var product_fire = [Product_]()
    private var db = Firestore.firestore()
    
    func fetchData() {
        db.collection("product_fire").addSnapshotListener{ (querySnapshot, error) in
            guard let documents = querySnapshot?.documents else{
                print("No documents")
                return
            }
            
            self.product_fire = documents.map{(queryDocumentSnapshot) -> Product_ in
                let data = queryDocumentSnapshot.data()
                
                let code = data["code"] as? String ?? ""
                let brands = data["brands"] as? String ?? ""
                let product_name = data["product_name"] as? String ?? ""
                let packaging1 = data["packaging1"] as? String ?? ""
                let packaging2 = data["packaging2"] as? String ?? ""
                let packaging3 = data["packaging3"] as? String ?? ""
                
                return Product_(code: code, brands:brands, product_name:product_name, packaging1:packaging1, packaging2:packaging2, packaging3:packaging3)
            }      
        } 
    } 
}
```

I have tried many things and the closest I have come is replacing the List() code with:

```
List(viewModel.product_fire, id: \.product_name) { product in
            NavigationLink(destination: ProductDetail(product: product))
            {ItemRow(product: product).navigationTitle("Products")
            }.onAppear(){
              self.viewModel.fetchData()
```

Edit to address XTwisteDX's comment:

```
        let data = queryDocumentSnapshot.data()          
        let code = data["code"] as? String ?? "No Code"
        let brands = data["brands"] as? String ?? "No Brand"
        //let product_name = data["product_name"] as? String ?? ""
        let packaging1 = data["packaging1"] as? String ?? "No Packaging1"
        let packaging2 = data["packaging2"] as? String ?? "No Packaging2"
        let packaging3 = data["packaging3"] as? String ?? "No Packaging3"
        let product_name = "Test Name"
```

This still gives me a blank screen when I run the ProductList file. So I am guessing that it is a problem from passing the data from ProductData to ProductList

This just gives me a blank screen, but when I look on the Firebase console there is reads happening so at least I know the connection is correct and I think the problem is how I am displaying the data.

Many thanks, been stuck on this for days.

Comment: Is it possible that you're not parsing your data properly? "Not Showing Anything" indicates that you may be getting back `""` from your `fetchData()` method. I suggest you change that to an `if let` statement and put in an `else` to handle errors and let you see exactly where it's failing at. Also, change that from MAP to `.getData` then manually parse to a new `Product`

Comment: I think one potential problem is that I called db.collections(product_fire) but my collection was called Products. But I still don't get any data read after this. @xTwisteDx I am unsure how to implement your suggestions sorry.

Comment: I did change product_name to a static variable:
let product_name = "Test name" in the hope that it would at least return that but sadly not.

Comment: Is your `print("No documents")` line getting called or is it moving on to the `map` call afterwards? None of the SwiftUI stuff matters if you aren't successfully getting the data in the original call.

Comment: The print statement where Firebase is initiailly called does print, but the "No documents" does not. So can we assume that it is moving on to the map without problems? I added a print statement after each of the let variables and they also print. So it looks to be that up until the return Product_(...) part everything works.

Comment: @BlueTurtle where are you calling `fetchData`? Also, you can assume that the `return` within `map` is working. You could double check how many entries are stored in your array by printing `self.product_fire` after your `map`. You may also want to explore using the debugger rather than having to rely on `print` statements.

Comment: @jnpdx Apologies, I have ammended the code near the end to include how I have tried to call fetchData()

Comment: @BlueTurtle it appears that you're calling `fetchData` on every row of the list in that code. Your `onAppear` should be somewhere where it'll be called *once* (ie outside of the `List`). Formatting your code will make it easier to see things like that (CTRL-i in Xcode).

Comment: @jnpdx Oh my gosh that was it! Simply moving it outside of the list worked perfectly. Please add that as an answer so I can accept it. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're calling `fetchData` on the `onAppear` of every item in your `List`. You need to move it *outside* the `List` so that it only gets called once.

```
List(...) {
 ///
}.onAppear {
  viewModel.fetchData()
}
```